# How to pass an external JSON file into a javascript variable that can be accessible anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a json file which I have been using in my project in this structure

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

<script>    
    var data = {"bills":[{"id":1,"name":"DStv","reference":"SmartCard Number","logo":"bill\/logo\/24Io6IqObQ8ddi5.jpg","active":1,"lifestyle":0},{"id":3,"name":"GOtv","reference":"IUC Number","logo":"bill\/logo\/mCNl5X1ZCfph4kg.jpg","active":1,"lifestyle":0},{"id":6,"name":"Startimes"...
</script>

<script src="js/bill.js"></script>
<script src="js/airtime.js"></script>
```

As you can see from the above example, the json file have already been passed to a data variable... of which I have other external javascript file placed under it.

Meanwhile, the json file is now generated/accessible from a link and I was told to use ajax to get the json data into the project.

I have this code in my `main.js` file, I have the below code but its not accessible in the `bills.js` file

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://example.com/bills/resources",
       success: function(result)
       {
           data = result;
           loadData(result);

       }
   });

});
```

Comment: Why don't you call the ajax inside bill.js ?

Comment: use namespace in javascript

Comment: @Fawaz, If i call the ajax inside bill.js, I wont be able to use it elsewhere like in airtime.js, other.js, etc. I want to be able to use it in any other external javascript file

Comment: @Solar Check my answer below. Run it on document ready and pass onto airtime, bill, other etc using custom events. Moreover, you can save it in a global variable like `window.result = result;` and access `window.result` from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

if it is a static variable and pulled just once then you can use Javascript cookie
instead of creating global variable in the same file in order to get the value where ever you need

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://bills.payit.ng/bills/resources",
       success: function(result)
       {
           data = result;
           setCookie("myStaticDataPerDay",data,1)
           loadData(result);

       }
   });
});

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

and you should be able to retrieve it by

```
console.log(getCookie("myStaticDataPerDay"));
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Also you can save it in jquery cookie

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://bills.payit.ng/bills/resources",
       success: function(result)
       {
           data = result;
           $.cookie('myStaticData', data);
           loadData(result);

       }
   });
});
```

and you will need to get the value by

```
var data=JSON.parse($.cookie("MyStaticData"))
```

**Update**
You can also use localStorage in case if you have IOS users because ios doesn't accept cookie

Comment: Use local storage instead. That will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use events to pass data :

```
// in ajax success
var event = new CustomEvent("custom-event", {data: result});
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

and then in your bill.js script or any place you need the data :

```
window.addEventListener("custom-event", function(e) {
  console.log("custom-event", e.data);
});
```